# Validate each object key in the object array with json schema in ajv

Tags: json, object, schema, ajv

I have an array which includes objects which have different key values. I want to validate each object key. For example, age field can get only Equal and Not equal operator values. So "op" key is different for each key. For example name should be used with Contains operator.

[

```
{ age:21, op: "Equal" },
{ name:21, op: "Contains" },
{ date: 1564577662198, op: "Not equal" }
```

]

I have written a schema as,

```
{
  "title": "ValidatorSchema",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "age":{
        "type": "number"
      },
      "operator" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "enum" : ["Equal" , "Not equal"]
      },
      "name":{
        "type": "string"
      },
      "operator" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "enum" : ["Contains"]
      }
     }
  }
}
```

But i couldn't relate each key with an operator. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to express the requirements (as best I understand them) using the "[JSON Extended Structural Schema](https://bitbucket.org/pkoppstein/jess)" language, JESS:

```
[
    ["&",
     {"comment": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291339/validate-each-object-key-in-the-object-array-with-json-schema-in-ajv",
      "::<=":  {
                 "age": "number",
                 "operator": "string",
                 "name": "string",
                 "date": "number"
      }
     },
     { "comment": "age field can get only Equal and Not equal operator values",
       "ifcond": { "has": "age"},
       "then":   ["&", {"forall": ".[operator]", "enumeration": ["Equal", "Not equal"]}]
     },
     { "comment": "name should be used with Contains operator",
       "ifcond": { "forall": ".[operator]", "equal": "Contains" },
       "then":   ["&", {"has": "name" } ]
     }
    ]
]
```

### Explanation

A JESS schema is a collection of JSON texts. Here, one JSON document suffices, as shown above.

The outer square brackets express the requirement that the target JSON entity must be a JSON array.

The "&" signifies that what follows is a conjunction of constraints.  Here there are three top-level constraints, each with a "comment" field to indicate what's going on. In brief:

1. The first top-level constraint expresses the requirement that the components of the array must contain objects formed using any of the indicated keys with the type constraint shown.
2. The second top-level constraint expresses the condition that the "age field can get only Equal and Not equal operator values".
3. The third expresses the constraint that if the value of .operator is "Contains" in an object, then that object must have a "name" key (the type of which has already been specified in (1.)).